# Scrolling up or down with ctrl moves cursor to first non whitespace

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I scroll using ctrl + up/down, the cursor is moved to the first non-whitespace character on the line, when it goes outside of the view. This is a bit annoying when I've placed the cursor in the left-most column on purpose (this is how I edit, sometimes).
You can see the effect more clearly with this keybinding:

```
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+down",
        "command": "editorScroll",
        "args": {
            "to": "down",
            "by": "line",
            "revealCursor": true
        }
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+up",
        "command": "editorScroll",
        "args": {
            "to": "up",
            "by": "line",
            "revealCursor": true
        }
    }
]
```

Can I toggle this behaviour off so that the cursor stays in the column where I've placed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use keyboard scrolling while keeping the cursor position at the same column, one workaround would be to use the [macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros) extension so that you can both scroll down and move the cursor down at the same time.

Add this to `settings.json`

```
    "macros": {
        "keyboardScrollDown": [
            {
                "command": "editorScroll",
                "args": {
                    "to": "down",
                    "by": "line",
                    "revealCursor": true
                }
            },
            "cursorDown"
        ],
        "keyboardScrollUp": [
            {
                "command": "editorScroll",
                "args": {
                    "to": "up",
                    "by": "line",
                    "revealCursor": true
                }
            },
            "cursorUp"
        ]
    },
```

Add this to `keybindings.json`

```
    {
        "key": "ctrl+down",
        "command": "macros.keyboardScrollDown"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+up",
        "command": "macros.keyboardScrollUp",
    },
```

Comment: I added this keybinding because I want to scroll using ctrl+up/down and have the cursor stay visible in the window. Both Sublime and Visual Studio have this (correct if you ask me) behaviour. I don't understand why VS Code needed to introduce another (nonstandard as I believe) behaviour

Comment: i must have mis-read your question before, i hope the new workaround helps

Comment: Very interesting! It doesn't work exactly like Sublime or VS but it is good enough to serve as a workaround, and I like it! Thanks!